# How to insert method in main App class LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

How can I add a method in the Illuminate\Support\Facades\App default class? Solutions?

Comment: Welcome to SO... and why would you like to do that? App facade is accessing Illuminate\Foundation\Application - main Laravel Application class - For whatever reason you intend to do that can be achieved by a different approach I guess.

Comment: i must add a function that will dynamically change the name of the project depending on the variable (numerical) set in the ENV. I'm gonna make a helper/AppHelper and call you from AppServiceProvider register() method?

Answer (score 1):

> i must add a function that will dynamically change the name of the
> project depending on the variable (numerical) set in the ENV

```
dd([
    putenv("APP_NAME=New_name"),
    env("APP_NAME")
]);

array:2 [
  0 => true
  1 => "New_name"
]
```